# Transaction tx = graphDatabaseService.beginTx(); is null in neo4j embedded version 2.3.8

Tags: java, neo4j

**Below is my code. When i call graphDatabaseService.beginTx() it is giving nullPointerException. Is there any other ways to create Transaction in Neo4j**

```
 protected Record getNext() throws Exception {  
Transaction tx = graphDatabaseService.beginTx();
    try {   
    if (hits == null) { 
        hits = index.query(query);
       tx.success(); 
    }
    T next = hits.next();
    if (next == null) {
        return finished();
    } else {
        return nodeToRecord.call(next);
    }
    }   
    finally{    
        closeIndexResults(hits);
         tx.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `graphDatabaseService` variable has a `null` value. Make sure you have properly initialized it before `getNext()` is called. For example:

```
GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase(dbPath);
```